# Difference in Markdown output and RStudio output in term of plot output

Tags: r, plot, statistics, dataframe, markdown

How can I make a density plot with rug of mpg for those cars with higher-than-or-equal-to-median horsepower and put in the bottom row (row=3) ? The problem is that the following code sounds to work (not sure if I am doing it right!!) in RStudio but when I am writing it in .rmd file and `knit` it into `html` it shows the plots one by one not similar to what is expected. Any idea what happens in knitting?

```
mat <- matrix(1:3, ncol=1, nrow=3)
mat <- rbind(cbind(0, mat), 0)
plot(density(mtcars$mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(mtcars$mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
lower_mpg=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg < 19.20]
plot(density(lower_mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(lower_mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
(summary(mtcars$mpg))
greater_mpg=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg >= 19.20]
plot(density(greater_mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(greater_mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
```

P.S.: If I don't tell the row number it just stacks them after each other and when I tell it, it gives me warning. However I am not sure if I am selecting the mtcars$mpg correctly?
P.S.: Can I define the xlim and ylim just once in the beginning? Like how?

```
> summary(mtcars$mpg)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.40   15.42   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90 
greater_mpg=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg >= 19.20]
```

What is shown in RStudio:
[image]
What I see in the knit html:
[image]

And here comes the problem definition which I believe I am doing it like 80% correctly:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up your plotting area with `layout` or `par`+`mfrow` or anything like that?

Comment: As suggested, you probably want to look at `mfrow` under `?par`, e.g. running `par(mfrow=c(3, 1))` before you start plotting.

Comment: @AnandaMahto So how is it working when I am running it in RStudio?

Comment: If you do `dev.off()` in RStudio, you might find that it no longer stacks the images until you once again set `mfrow` in `par`. You may have set it at some stage during your R session without realising it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments I used the following code and it works in `markdown` as well:

```
par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
mat <- rbind(cbind(0, mat), 0)
plot(density(mtcars$mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(mtcars$mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
lower_mpg=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg < 19.20]
plot(density(lower_mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(lower_mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
(summary(mtcars$mpg))
greater_mpg=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg >= 19.20]
plot(density(greater_mpg),ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
rug(greater_mpg, col=2, lwd=3.5,ylim=c(0,0.15), xlim=c(0,40))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to assign `par` to anything, it just sets the plotting parameters for the currently active plotting device. However, if, for example, you assigned it like this: `opar <- par(mfrow=c(3, 1))`, then you could later reinstate the pre-existing plotting parameters with `par(opar)`. (Your assignment to `mat` won't work like this since you subsequently overwrite `mat` with your matrix)

Comment: I've edited your answer (which you could accept, by the way), but the way you had it was also fine. Just a redundant assignment of `par`.

Comment: I prefer to control figure size (and ratio) through chunk options. See  http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/r_markdown under `Embedded code`.